# Using HTTP basic auth for certain URLs only with Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication, http-auth

I have a node.js application designed using the Express framework and the [http-auth](http://http-auth.info) module, as follows:

```
var auth = require('http-auth');
var express = require('express');
// ...
var mywebapp = express();
// ...
if (usebasicauth) {
  var basic = auth.basic({realm:"MyRealm", file:"/srv/config/passwd"});
  mywebapp.use(auth.connect(basic));
}

mywebapp.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/files/js'));
mywebapp.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/files/css'));
// ...
```

However, I don't want to protect assets available under the `/js` and `/css` directories. This is what I tried doing:

```
if (usebasicauth) {
  var basic = auth.basic({realm:"MyRealm", file:"/srv/config/passwd"});
  mywebapp.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (/^\/(css|js)/.test(req.url)) {
      next();
    }
    else {
      auth.connect(basic);
    }
  });
}
```

Trying to access URLs under `/css` and `/js` work as expected; however, other URLs never load.

How can I make other URLs work as expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order of `mywebapp.use` is important.
If you have first `mywebapp.use(auth.connect(basic));` then it will be used for every request
but if you change the order it will pass statics and be only used for whatever is after it.

**The middleware functions are processed in order they are added.**

So following should do what you want.

```
// no auth for statics
mywebapp.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/files/js'));
mywebapp.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/files/css'));
// auth reguired from here 
mywebapp.use(auth.connect(basic));
```

If you place `mywebapp.use(auth.connect(basic));` above express.static it will reguire auth for it as well.

```
// auth reguired from here 
mywebapp.use(auth.connect(basic));
// auth required for statics as well
mywebapp.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/files/js'));
mywebapp.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/files/css'));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this as well https://gist.github.com/gevorg/7168d5f02c1ca5362b2a#file-specific-path-js

```
// Express module.
var express = require('express');

// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if ('/specific/path' === req.path) {
        next();
    } else {
        (auth.connect(basic))(req, res, next);
    }
});

// Setup route.
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send("Hello from express - " + req.user + "!");
});

// Setup guest route.
app.get('/specific/path', function(req, res){
  res.send("Hello from express - guest!");
});

// Start server.
app.listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to this question is not desirable, as the route order can be important!

A better way to do it would be to pass basic-auth as second argument for your route definition:

```
app.get('/admin', auth.connect(basic), (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello from admin area - ${req.user}!`);
});
```

Or

```
app.use('/admin', auth.connect(basic), myCustomRoute);
```